# I need to send an argument to the cx_Freeze.Executable

Tags: python, python-3.7, cx-freeze

I need to send an argument in the cx_Freeze.Executable. The argument to send is `-c C: \ Users \ EA_E90434 \ Desktop \ RTC \ RTC \ refresh.ini`

I am new to python. I am running the main script now it this way:

```
python main.py -c C: \ Users \ EA_E90434 \ Desktop \ RTC \ RTC \ refresh.ini
```

Now what I am doing is to make an exe of this script using the following `setup.py`:

```
import sys

import cx_Freeze

sys.argv.append("build")

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("main.py",
                                    base="Win32GUI",
                                    icon=None,)]


if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os","descryp","pip._vendor.distlib.compat","app","pyaes","logging","cx_Oracle"],
                     "include_files" : ["app.py","descryp.py","classes","classes/config.py","classes/AesECB.py"]}


cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="prueba",
    version="1.0",
    description="prueba",
    options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables=executables
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Open a `cmd` or terminal window, change to the directory of your frozen executable, and (assuming it is named `main.exe`) start it with:

```
main.exe -c C: \ Users \ EA_E90434 \ Desktop \ RTC \ RTC \ refresh.ini
```

This should work exactly as when you start your unfrozen script with

```
python main.py -c C: \ Users \ EA_E90434 \ Desktop \ RTC \ RTC \ refresh.ini
```